# MIPS turning pixel into memory address

Tags: mips, mips32, mars-simulator

I have been given an exercise for my course and could use some help with it. We have to turn a pixel (row x column) into its memory address and print it. $gp is pixel 0x0 and every pixel is 32 bits. How would I go about calculating let's say pixel 0,1?

(width = 32px, height = 16px)

I've looked everywhere in our course information and can't seem to find anything to help me out.

Comment: You have to multiply the **y** coordinate by the screen width (and pixel size which is 4 bytes) then add **xx** multiplied by pixel size (again 4). Also check whether y axis is inverted (I dont recall if y=0 is bottom or top)

Comment: heya! thanks for the reply, isn't the pixel size 32 here? that's what was said in our exercise. 'one pixel is 32 bits' also 0x0 is top left 
*edit, you're right! 32bits = 4 bytes sorry!*

Comment: Given a coordinate, you can compute using [row major formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).  The idea is that for a given row position we need to skip ahead over lower-numbered whole rows, so that's why the row number gets multiplied by the row width, then add column number (and then scale per element size) and add base address.

Comment: by pixel 0x1 I meant 0,1

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you do `y * width + x = index`. Then you have to multiply the index by the size of the pixel to get the `offset` and finally `$gp + offset`.

Comment: Effectively this formula converts a 2D array into a 1D array for the purposes of indexing, as all computer memory is one-dimensional in practice.